# C++ Restricting the inner type in a template template

Tags: c++, templates, stl

Is there a way in C++ to specify the type of the inner template in a nested template? What I want to do is

```
template<template <std::string> class StringContainer>
void function(const StringContainer& cont);
```

In other words, I want a function that accepts all types of string containers -- `vector`s, `deque`s, `list`s, etc.

Basically, I have four questions:

1. Is it possible to do so?
2. If so, how should the definition look like (the above doesn't compile, but I didn't expect it to)?
3. Even if possible, is there a way to make it work with the standard containers, which have more than one template parameters, which might even be implementation-specific?
4. If not containers, can I at least expect iterators to have only one template parameter?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you actually want to do? Normally, generic algorithms should impose only the least requirements to the types (to be most generic).

Comment: One option would be to check if nested typedef `value_type` evaluates to `std::string`.

Comment: *Side remark:* `template <std::string> class TT` would denote a template (not a type) with a non-type template parameter of type `std::string`. This itself isn't valid as `std::string` is not a valid type for a non-type parameter. OTOH, `template <class> class TT` denotes a template with a type parameter, and [it compiles fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa6560b8991a689f).

Comment: DyP: yes, but function() isn't meant to be generic, it expects a string container. Currently I am using `vector`, but I want to work with `list` and `deque` as well.

Comment: jrok: How do I do that? Also, I kind of want to document what my function does with the (template) signature, and not enforce the restriction programatically. Still, I'd very much like to see how it is done. :)

Comment: @DyP : your example is not exactly what I wanted, but it doesn't look bad. I was just wondering if it is possible to put the std::string in the template definition...

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <deque>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// Removed:
// template < template<typename, typename ...> class Container, 
// typename T, typename ...Types>
// void function(const Container<T, Types...>&);

template < template<typename ...> class Container, typename ...Types>
void function(const Container<std::string, Types...>& container) {
    for(const std::string& s: container) {
        std::cout << s << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main () {
    std::deque<std::string> d{ "Hello", "Deque" };
    function(d);
    std::list<std::string> l{ "Hello", "List" };
    function(l);
    std::vector<std::string> v{ "Hello", "Vector" };
    function(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer a compiler error to a linker error.  maybe give the generic overload a body containing a static_assert?  Wait, is the generic overload needed at all?

Comment: [Nope, the first overload isn't needed.](http://ideone.com/H7nNDr), and you get better error messages without it

Comment: Cute +1!  Except `std::pair< std::string, int > p; function(p);`?

Comment: @Yakk Which fails miserable (no constraints applied)

Comment: @Yakk ... at compile time

Comment: @Yakk `pair` does not fulfil the requirements for containers (as you actually pointed out yourself by checking `begin` and `end`) and the OP wants a function that accepts "all types of string containers"

Comment: @Dyp I was trying to say "cute trick, it only accepts overrides for `std::string` containers: however, other things will be accepted as matching, then fail when the body is instantiated with obscure error messages", but I instead made my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but the direction you are going is not a wise one.

Instead, I would advise thinking about things via duck typing.  If your function needs to iterate over the contents of the thing passed in, and expects the contents to be strings, what you are looking for is "this argument matches the concept of a sequence of `std::string`s".

That is best done in C++14 via the requires syntax, but you probably don't have C++14 compliant compilers yet, unless you are posting via time machine.

We can do this in C++11 via traits classes, SFINAE, and `enable_if`.  Alternatively, we can do this in C++11 via traits classes and tag dispatching.  Tag dispatching is less arcane than SFINAE, so I'll demonstrate it here.

We start with a generic function:

```
template<typename C>
void function( C const& c )
```

that accepts anything.  Next, we write some traits class:

```
template<typename C,typename=void>
struct is_string_sequence : std::false_type {};
template<typename C>
struct is_string_sequence<C, typename std::enable_if<TODO STUFF HERE>::type> : std::true_type {};
```

that tells us if the argument passed in is a sequence over strings.

Next, we write a helper function:

```
template<typename C>
void function_helper( C const& c, std::true_type string_sequence_test ) {
  // your code goes here, and can assume c is a string sequence
}
```

and forward the first one to it:

```
template<typename C>
void function( C const& c ) {
  function_helper( c, is_string_sequence<C>() );
}
```

but we also create a tag to pass to the helper.  This tag is true if our tests pass, and false if not.  As we only have an override for true, the false case generates an error, and that error tends to be reasonably readable.

The only thing left is to write `TODO STUFF HERE`.

The duck-type way to tell if something is a string sequence in C++11 is to see if:

```
for( std::string s : c ) {
}
```

compiles.  A way to do this is to see if `begin` and `end` free functions applied to `c` in a context where `std::begin` and `std::end` are visible returns iterators, and those iterators when dereferenced produce a type that is convertible to `std::string`.

This requires some gymnastics.  First, seeing what `begin` and `end` result in when called in that particular context:

```
namespace adl_helper {
  using std::begin; using std::end;
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_begin( C&& c )->decltype( begin(std::forward<C>(c)) );
  template<typename C>
  auto adl_end( C&& c )->decltype( end(std::forward<C>(c)) );
}
using adl_helper::adl_begin; using adl_helper::adl_end;
```

note that these have no bodies: for our purposes, we don't need bodies, we just need the return types.

Now we can ask "is something a container?"

```
template<typename C, typename=void>
struct is_container : std::false_type {};
template<typename C>
struct is_container<C, typename=typename std::enable_if<
  std::is_convertible<
    decltype( adl_begin( std::declval<C&>() ) == adl_end( std::declval<C&>() ) ),
    bool
  >::value
>::type> : std::true_type
{
  typedef decltype( adl_begin( std::declval<C&>() ) ) iterator;
};
```

a fancier one might probe into `iterator_traits` instead (above, I just check that the `begin` and `end` work, and the results have an overridden `==` between them that returns something that can be converted to `bool`).

We can then ask if the resulting iterator has a value type that can be converted to `std::string` in another traits class.

Alternatively we can do a `decltype( *adl_begin( std::declval<C&>() ) )`, and see if that can be directly converted to `std::string`, and assume if `begin` works so will `end`.

The SFINAE method is similar, except instead of doing the tag dispatching to a helper, we put the test directly into the `function` signature, wrapped in an `enable_if` that activates or deactivates the `function` for overload resolution.  This generates slightly harder to read errors but at a higher point in the call stack in my experience.

You don't do the approach you where aiming at, because the details of how the container was built from other types are not important: what is important is how you use it.

If you need other features form your type other than iteration, you can write other duck-type tests that determine if you can erase, insert, etc.  However, note that associative containers and sequential containers are very different things, and treating them uniformly is rarely a good idea, other than in that both are sequences.

Comment: `std::is_string_sequence<C>` are you in the Committee? ;)

Comment: 1) Maybe a `static_assert` is more appropriate here than selecting overloads. 2) Isn't there a `typename` missing before `enable_if<is_convertible<...>{}>::type`?

Comment: @Dyp Yep, a few typos -- fixed!  `static_assert` is another option that isn't bad, and lets you craft a custom error message to.